# Not receiving notifications using Instagram Realtime API

Tags: instagram-api, webhooks, geofencing

I'm using the Intagram Realtime API which the doc is here https://instagram.com/developer/realtime/ in order to receive a notification every time someone takes a picture in a geofence.

I'm using this structure but my URL is not being called when I take a photo inside the fence:

```
curl -F 'client_id=CLIENT-ID' \
 -F 'client_secret=CLIENT-SECRET' \
 -F 'object=geography' \
 -F 'aspect=media' \
 -F 'lat=35.657872' \
 -F 'lng=139.70232' \
 -F 'radius=1000' \
 -F 'callback_url=http://my_public_url' \
 https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions/
```

Trying to list the Instagram subscriptions in order to see if my subscription is there, I got the following response:

```
{
  "meta":  {
    "code": 200
  },
  "data":  [{
    "object": "geography",
    "object_id": "12921209",
    "aspect": "media",
    "callback_url": "http://my_public_url",
    "type": "subscription",
    "id": "19351203"
  }]
}
```

The weird thing to notice is that the fields, lat, lng and radius are not being shown.

Any ideas how to make everything work?

Answer (score 1):

You need to query Instagram with that location ID after you receive a notification that new media has been posted matching your criteria. That object is designed to let you know what you need to ask Instagram for, not to give you media info.